# How to optimize MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

I have many query such like following query. 
How i get optimize them-

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  n.nid AS nid, n.title AS title, n.created AS created, n.changed AS changed,
  n.type AS type, n.status AS status, n.uid AS uid, u.name AS name,
  fit.field_item_topic_tid AS field_item_topic_tid,
  fui.field_upload_item_fid AS field_upload_item_fid,
  fist.field_item_sub_topic_tid AS field_item_sub_topic_tid,
  asid.field_item_asset_id_value AS field_item_asset_id_value,
  fur.field_item_urgent_value AS field_item_urgent_value,
  scrubbing.field_item_scrubbing_value AS field_item_scrubbing_value,
  wsts.field_item_workflow_status_value AS field_item_workflow_status_value,
  wfs.state AS state
FROM 
node n
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_item_topic fit ON n.nid=fit.entity_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_upload_item fui ON fui.entity_id= n.nid
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_item_sub_topic fist ON n.nid=fist.entity_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_item_asset_id asid ON n.nid=asid.entity_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_item_urgent fur ON fur.entity_id= n.nid
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_item_scrubbing scrubbing ON scrubbing.entity_id= n.nid
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_item_workflow_status wsts ON wsts.entity_id = n.nid
LEFT OUTER JOIN workflow_states wfs ON wfs.sid = wsts.field_item_workflow_status_value
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON u.uid = n.uid
WHERE ( (n.type = 'item') )
AND( (wsts.field_item_workflow_status_value IN  ('All', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10')) )
AND(    (fit.field_item_topic_tid IN  ('NULL', '46', '47', '48', '52', '73', '90', '118', '142', '150', '154', '175', '196', '362', '363', '366', '367', '383', '403', '406', '533', '535', '543'))
     OR (fist.field_item_sub_topic_tid IN  ('NULL', '50', '51', '66', '67', '70', '71', '74', '75', '76', '93', '143', '151', '197', '198', '206', '211', '304', '364', '368', '384', '404', '407', '534', '536'))
)
ORDER BY n.changed desc
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

```
EXPLAIN-
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  wsts    range   entity_id,field_item_workflow_status_value  field_item_workflow_status_value    5   NULL    1708    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  wfs     eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   lightening1.wsts.field_item_workflow_status_value   1    
1   SIMPLE  n   eq_ref  PRIMARY,node_type,nid   PRIMARY     4   lightening1.wsts.entity_id  1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  u   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   lightening1.n.uid   1    
1   SIMPLE  fit     ref     entity_id   entity_id   4   lightening1.wsts.entity_id  1    
1   SIMPLE  fui     ref     entity_id   entity_id   4   lightening1.wsts.entity_id  1    
1   SIMPLE  fist    ref     entity_id   entity_id   4   lightening1.n.nid   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  asid    ref     entity_id   entity_id   4   lightening1.wsts.entity_id  1    
1   SIMPLE  fur     ref     entity_id   entity_id   4   lightening1.wsts.entity_id  1    
1   SIMPLE  scrubbing   ref     entity_id   entity_id   4   lightening1.n.nid   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included table structures (especially indexes), so I can just provide half answer. First, notice in output this line:

```
1   SIMPLE  wsts    range   entity_id,field_item_workflow_status_value  field_item_workflow_status_value    5   NULL    1708    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

It means it has to look manually 1708 records. Indexes etc were used but 1708 remained. Those records will be sorted using files which are known to be slow.

in query

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_item_workflow_status wsts ON wsts.entity_id = n.nid
```

does some selection based on table field_data_field_item_workflow_status. I think you have to focus if you can add index there. If index exists, maybe it can be described better? If index is there, maybe field length can be made shorter? Indexes are getting bigger with bigger datatypes. So try to use TINYINT instead of INT when possible.

Anyway you are close :)

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing it's as simple as some indexes were left off.